# Does the value of a convolution with a gaussian on a subset of the space uniquely determines the function

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, convolution

I would like to understand if the following is true: Let $X$ be a continuous bounded-support random variable over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $Z = N(0,I)$ be a standard Gaussian independent of $X$. Say that we know the density of $X + Z$ (i.e. the convolution of densities of $X$ and $Z$) at some open set $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Does this uniquely determine $X$? In other words, can there be two probability distributions, $X$ and $X'$, such that $X+Z$ and $X'+Z$ have the same density on $D$?

If this is not true, then I would be interested to know whether $X$ can be uniquely recovered from the values of the densities of $\{X+Z_a\}_{a \in [1,1+\epsilon]}$ at $D$, where $Z_a \sim N(0, aI)$ independently of $X$.

Comment: Convolution requires independence.

Comment: When someone writes $X+Z$, it pretty much assumes independence of the two random variables.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC That is a bit of a stretch,

Comment: true, just edited that $X$ and $Z$ are independent

Comment: Isn't the density of X+Z analytic? This should then imply your claim.